# Running Import-Module Active Directory for Script On Computer that has RSAT through Shortcut

Tags: powershell, command, shortcut

I currently have a script that opens up a GUI that will run a `Get-ADUser` cmdlet. It opens through a shortcut where I provide an `-executionpolicy` bypass. It is currently working on my computer, but not anyone elses. The GUI will come up and run, but will not search. I'm thinking it is because it has not ever loaded `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`. Putting it in the beginning of script does not work. When I put it as a `-command Import-ActiveDirectory` into my shortcut it is still not working. Any idea why this is not working on other computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear with your question, Is RSAT installed on the machine that is running the script?

Does the User who is running the script on there machine have credentials to read Active Directory?

Are you able to share any of the script ?

Are you able to run `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` outside of the script on the other computers? if so, what is the error?

Comment: Yes it has been installed on the machine. I notice that I would have to run `import-module activedirectory` `get-aduser first.last` before I can do the Get-ADUser, however, on my computer it auto-loads Import-Module AD without me having to tell it to. Therefore that's why I believe I must tell this computer to import it first. How did I manage to get my computer to import-module and stick? Or how can I bypass this issue?

Comment: You would, in order for the script to work. Since your script is having issue though and you think it is to do with `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` Have you tried running this outside of the script? just in the powershell terminal window?

Comment: You're right, it's not liking my 'passthru' parameter...I didn't notice because I had the CMD hidden. Hold on! >_<

Comment: If this is the case then we can mark this as a successful answer and everyone's happy :)

Comment: I'll close this, but I'm going to have to ask why on this particular computer I cannot use my `Out-GridView -Title "Search Results" -passthru` The -passthru is kicking out saying:  `Out-GridView : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'passthru'`

Comment: If you mark this as answered you can always raise another question!

Is there a difference between the versions of PowerShell that your machine and this other computer is using?

Comment: @DrixlRey i believe PowerShell 3 is where -passthru became available to alot more cmdlets. So if your other machine is running PowerShell 2 then that would be your issue

Comment: @DrixlRey just following up today, how did you go?

If all is working now can you please mark this as answered so others searching with similar questions may find what they are looking for!

Comment: Yes it was because the computers I ran it on was a PS2 or lower. It did not like -passthru This is solved!

Comment: Awesome glad it's solved!! Can we mark an answer so that others with this issue can find our solution!